# ¿Qué quiere decir "señorito"?

Tags: colombia, saludos

Me gustaría saber si alguien te dice "Sí señorito" o algo así, por ejemplo, en Colombia, te está burlando o si se trata de una frase normal. Yo personalmente solo la he oído un par de veces en Colombia. Normalmente la gente te dice "caballero" o "joven" o algo así. Por eso me pregunta si el uso de "señorito" tiene otro significado o alguna insinuación.

Tambien me gustaría saber porqué la forma femenina o sea "señorita" es muy conocida incluso entre los que no hablan castellano, pero la forma masculina casi no se usa. Verdad es que ni se me había ocurrido que hubiera una forma masculina.

Comment: Aunque en aquel post se da una respuesta, esta es solo parcial para esta pregunta, y además el contexto de aquella pregunta era completamente diferente. No considero que esta pregunta sea un duplicado de aquella, por lo que valdría la pena traerse las partes relevantes de aquella respuesta e incluso ampliarla un poco.

Comment: No es un duplicado (de hecho, no veo ningún voto para cerrar esta pregunta), pero sí daba una información útil. Una pena que haya desaparecido el comentario donde se mencionaba la otra pregunta.

Comment: No tengo tiempo para una respuesta formal, pero como Colombiano te digo que ese tratamiento es normal y no implica ninguna insinuación. Aunque no es regla tal vez lo único implícito es que casi siempre lo dice una mujer a un hombre mucho más joven (y probablemente soltero). El uso de "caballero" es más formal y usar "joven" denota neutralidad mientras que "señorito" es más jovial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me temo que no puedo darte una explicación específica para Colombia.

De acuerdo con el D.R.A.E

[**señorito, ta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XcT6x6x)

> Del dim. de señor.
>
> 1. m. y f. Hijo de un señor o de persona de representación.
> 2. m. y f. coloq. Persona, especialmente si es joven, a la que sirve un criado.
> 3. m. coloq. **Joven** acomodado y ocioso.
> 4. f. U. como tratamiento de cortesía aplicado a la **mujer soltera**.

El masculino **señorito** en España puede emplearse en tono de mofa e incluso peyorativo dirigido a un varón si éste trata a alguien como si fuera su criado, dándole ordenes o tratándolo con desprecio, o se comporta de una forma excesivamente remilgada, cual si fuera un joven acomodado y con criados, acostumbrado a que estos obedezcan sus ordenes y satisfagan sus caprichos, pero sin serlo realmente.

El femenimo es más conocido entre los no castellano-hablantes por las palabras que he marcado en negro: joven, mujer, soltera.

Y también porque es el equivalente al tratamiento de cortesía en inglés **miss**, que se emplea independientemente de la capacidad económica o la edad aplicado a una mujer soltera. Creo que no existe tratamiento de cortesía equivalente en inglés para hombre soltero, tanto para casados como para solteros se emplea **Mr** (mister) que deriva de master como apuntaba @guifa y que debe usarse precediento el apellido, ya que sin él

**[mister](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mister)**

> variant form of Mr, often used **humorously or with offensive emphasis**

Comment: En el inglés el tratamiento para un no casado, hoy efectivamente extinto, era *master*

Comment: @guifa Puede ser, pero no aparece en el Oxford esa acepción. Lo más parecido que veo es el señor de la casa, el pater familias. Nótese que podría tener otros hombres casados bajo su techo que no serían master.

Comment: es la 22.ª acepción en la entrada de master en el OED: *a. With reference to a boy or a young man.  (a) Applied  [subsequent to the phonetic separation of mister n.2] as a prefix to the name of a boy or young man not considered old enough to be called ‘Mr.’;*

Comment: @guifa Tienes razón, esa la había visto, pero la mayoría de ejemplos que aparecen incluyen el adjetivo "young" también. Me da la impresión de que en ese contexto se traduciría por "señorito" con las implicaciones que eso deriva en castellano de joven acomodado en lugar de solamente joven, soltero o no.

Comment: ¿Qué tiene a ver señorito con el inglés mister? Absolutamente nada. Mister no es un tratamiento de cortesía. Es cosa de cine western o como se trata a un desconocido en ciertas regiones de los EEUU y nada tiene que ver con la edad de un hombre. A veces es aun un poco "baja clase", decirlo.

Comment: @murderof crows Que pena. Me gustan los cuervos. "Hey, mister, whaddya want here anyways?"//“Never apologize, mister, it’s a sign of weakness.” John Wayne

Comment: @murder of crows Yo lo sé. Pride of lions, exaltation of larks, conosco casi todos.

Comment: @Lambie Pues según el Oxford Dictionary, mister es una variante de Mr. "A title used before a surname or full name to address or refer to a man without a higher or honorific or professional title.", cuyo significado parece denotar cortesía, como apuntaba. Culpa mía no señalarlo explícitamente en el texto. El cual a su vez viene de master, como apuntaba guifa.

Comment: @RubioRic El tema no es: ***Mr. Smith*** is my friend. El ***Señor Smith*** es mi amigo. No es "cortesia", es ***formal***. Pero aqui estabamos discutiendo: mister sin un nombre. (Claro, en los dos casos se pronuncia de la misma forma porque Mr. viene de mister).

Answer (score 1):

Similar a la respuesta de RubioRic, señorito se usa de gente mayor o superiores hacia personas jovenes o de menor estatus de forma peyorativa cuando los hablantes saben de tu procedencia. Aunque también posee un significado propio en contexto, como cuando una mujer se lo dice a un hombre (misma edad o menor que el hombre) de forma educada y cariñosa, o incluso de mujeres mayores a hombres muy jovenes que no precisamente sean solteros, eso si, depende del tono y el contexto de la conversación el que te dirá, si ella te lo dice como "halago" o como insulto.